# Which element does the yahoo pipes "unique" module return

Tags: unique, yahoo-pipes

If there are multiple matching elements, which element does the yahoo pipes "unique" module return? Is it the first, the last or can it be any?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=operators#Unique):

> This module removes items that contain duplicate strings. You select the element to filter on, and Unique removes the duplicates - if the original feed has five items with the same title, you can configure Unique so only one of these items is included in the output feed.

It would seem unspecified. However, after a couple of tests, it seems to me that the first item is selected. So you should be able to get the right items selected by using a **Sort** operator before **Unique**.

To illustrate this, I created 2 example pipes. In both pipes there are 3 input items with attributes:

- author=jack title=Bazaar
- author=jack title=Git
- author=jack title=Arch

In the [first pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=3fcfc9c22acfe1c7bfeb37ead72816b4), using the **Unique** operator selects the first item. If you delete the first item, it selects the second.

In the [second pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=25a0dcf0c8e4885cbdcd860a93600cab), I used the **Sort** operator to order the items by title before piping to **Unique**. This way Arch is selected. If you delete it, then Bazaar is selected, and so on.